# I've been learning the basics of calculus, specially limits but didnt understand this part.

Tags: limits

What is the value of

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}1^x$$
Especially for this question, some answers say that this is undefined and some say its $1$.
What is correct and why, and should we use the L'Hopital Rule here?
Thanks,

Comment: Who says it's undefined?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please don't post answers - use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . For this question, why do you need L'Hopital or any too, and who says it's undefined? $1^x$ is always just $1$ for any positive $x$, so that is the limit.

Comment: My guess is OP is confused between the limit

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} 1^x$$

and the indeterminant form

$$1^\infty$$

Comment: But Infinity is not a number, its something we assume that is endless or greater than any number. So in terms of working how can we prove that this limit evaluates to 1. My other friends as well agree it has to undefined.

Comment: So in that case then even 0^infinity is zero, but isnt 0^x defined to be 0 for x is a subset of real numbers, whereas infinity is not.

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = c$?  It is ***not*** evaluating $f(x)$ at $x=\infty$ and seeing that $f(\infty)=c$.

Comment: Intuitive approach : consider the sequence $a_n = 1^n ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, which looks like this: $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 1, \cdots$.  What is the limit of this sequence, as $n \to \infty~$ ?  For any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N = 1.$  Then, for all $n \geq N$, you have that $|a_n - 1| < \epsilon.$

Comment: You are correct that the symbol $\infty$ here is not meant to be a number. But it does have a meaning. The notation $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ for any function $f(x)$ has a very precise definition which your friends apparently have never seen. Have you seen the definition?

Answer (score 2):

For all $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N = 1.$

Then, for all $x \geq N$, you have that $|1^x - 1| < \epsilon.$

Per the definition of a limit, this is game over.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is defined, and it is equal to $1$. Note that $1^x  = 1$ for **all** $x\in \Bbb R$. The right-hand side is *independent* of $x$, so we can take limits as $x\to \infty$ to get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} 1^x = 1$$